# Two parameters out of three not reaching the Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I have the following in my Spring 4 controller. I am trying to add a record into a tablein database.
I am not sure why the parameters `testingID_` and `definition` I am supplying using POSTMAN client are not reaching the controller.
However, parameter `type_id` is reaching as explained below.

This is evident from the following facts:

When I used `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/addEmployeeRecord?employee_id=1234&type_id=4444&definition=test1212`

1) I  checked the console output for the following line :

```
logger.info("addEmployeeRecord ws params : " + 

                            "value="+definition+
                            ",employee_id="+testingID_+
                            ",type_id="+type_id+
                            ",rank="+rank
                            );
```

And I noticed the following in the console logs:

```
addEmployeeRecord ws params : value=,employee_id=0,type_id=4444,rank=1
```

2) I checked by injecting `HttpServletRequest` as shown below and I saw all the parameters reaching when the following line is 
executed :

```
request.getParameterMap().entrySet().forEach(entry -> logger.info("Parameter: " + entry.getKey() + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue())));
```

Here are the results:

```
Parameter: employee_id[1234]
Parameter: type_id[4444]
Parameter: definition[test1212]
```

Since `testingID_` is always `0` which is default value and less than `1` , I am always getting `Invalid Employee ID parameter` exception. How can I troubleshoot this?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addEmployeeRecord", method=RequestMethod.GET)
                public String addEmployeeRecord
                (
                    @RequestParam(value="employee_id", defaultValue="0") Integer testingID_,
                    @RequestParam(value="type_id", defaultValue="0") Integer type_id,  
                    @RequestParam(value="value", defaultValue="") String definition,
                    @RequestParam(value="rank", defaultValue="1") Integer rank,
                    HttpServletRequest request

                ) 
                {

                    String wsStatusJsonString = null;

                    logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    logger.info("HttpRequest Parameters Check");
                    request.getParameterMap().entrySet().forEach(entry -> logger.info("Parameter: " + entry.getKey() + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue())));
                    logger.info("addEmployeeRecord ws params : " + 

                            "value="+definition+
                            ",employee_id="+testingID_+
                            ",type_id="+type_id+
                            ",rank="+rank
                            );

                    boolean addStatus = true;       
                    try {

                        // Validate the input parameters.
                        if (testingID_ < 1 ) {throw new Exception("Invalid Employee ID parameter"); }
                        if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(definition)) { throw new Exception("Invalid  Definition Parameter");}

                        //some code


                        logger.info("addEmployeeRecord status:" + addStatus);
                        if (addStatus) {
                            wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(true, "Successfully Inserted Employee Record!", true);
                        } else {
                            wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(true, "Error ! Unable to Insert Employee Record !", true);
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable th) {
                        th.printStackTrace();
                        wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(false, th.getMessage(), true);
                    }

                    logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    return wsStatusJsonString;
                }
```

Comment: @DwB Where exactly I am missing `&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller method, `@RequestParam(value="value", defaultValue="") String definition` is declared whereas you are passing `definition=test1212` as the query parameter, to pass definition you need to set `value=test1212` instead. I used below code to test the req param:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployeeRecord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployeeRecord(@RequestParam(value = "employee_id", defaultValue = "0") Integer testingID_,
            @RequestParam(value = "type_id", defaultValue = "0") Integer type_id,
            @RequestParam(value = "value", defaultValue = "") String definition,
            @RequestParam(value = "rank", defaultValue = "1") Integer rank, HttpServletRequest request

    ) {

        try {

            // Validate the input parameters.
            if (testingID_ < 1) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Employee ID parameter");
            }
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(definition)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid  Definition Parameter");
            }

            // some code

        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "testingID_ " + testingID_ + " type_id- " + type_id + " definition " + definition + " rank " + rank;
    }
```

Postman capture is:

[image: Postman Request and Response]

Comment: I tried changing it to `value`. Still getting same error.

Comment: I ran your code and tested with postman - `http://localhost:8080/mappings/addEmployeeRecord?employee_id=1234&type_id=4444&value=test1212`  I added a return statement as return `"testingID_ " + testingID_ + " type_id- " + type_id + " definition " + definition + " rank " + rank;` and the response returned was `testingID_ 1234 type_id- 4444 definition test1212 rank 1`

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it's not working at my end. Do you think I should try changing tomcat container?

Comment: I used SpringBoot to test your code, so I had embedded Tomcat to test your code.

Comment: Hmm, I will try changing the location of webservice end point to some different controller java class and see how it behaves there. Any other trouble shooting steps you would recommend?

Comment: Updated my response with the code and Postman screenshot, strange how its not working for you. And you are sure that it is hitting your controller? I would recommend you to clean the project and rebuild it, then re-deploy it.

Comment: Hmm, I will try to clean it. It's hitting because I am getting the `type_id` value every time except the other two.

Comment: The issue was resolved after cleaning the project and updating the maven project (I updated because the project wan't getting deployed on the server for some reason after cleaning), it works fine now. Thanks for you help.